# How to return/get List in PHP Post method?

Tags: php, database, laravel, list, post

I am new to PHP and Laravel and facing issues while returning/getting all student objects via PHP post method. What I am trying to do is when "SAVE" button is clicked all values either Present/Absent against every student is saved. Right now it is only returning me the last student for all records and saving it. i.e. if there are 100 students, 100 times last student's attendance is saved. Here is my code:

```
<form action="store_attendence_student" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="control-label">Date:</label>
            <input name="attendecnedate" type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
    @foreach($stdcourse1 as $d)     
        <h3> {{$d->student_registration_num}}</h3>
        <h3> {{$d->student_name}}</h3>
        <input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="{{$d->student_registration_num}}" >
        <input type="hidden" name="s_name" value="{{$d->student_name}}" >
      <select name="atten">
                <option value="present">Present</option>
                <option value="absent">Absent</option>
            </select>
      @endforeach
  <div class="form-layout-footer" style="margin-left: 40%">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success mg-r-5">  Save</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is Controller's Save Action:

```
public function store_attendence_student(Request $request)
{
     $data7=teachers::select('teacher_id')->where('teacher_email','=',Session::get('teacher_username'))->pluck('teacher_id')->first();

     $course1= teachers::select('course_id')->where('teacher_id','=',$data7)->pluck('course_id')->first();

     $stdcourse1=student::leftjoin('courses','courses.sem_id','=','students.sem_id')->where('courses.id','=',$course1)
    ->select('students.student_name','students.student_id')->count();


     for ($i=0; $i < $stdcourse1 ; $i++) 
     { 
        $attendence = new attendence();
        $attendence->student_id=$request->s_id;
        $attendence->student_name=$request->s_name;
        $attendence->course_id=$course1;
        $attendence->teacher_id=$data7;
        $attendence->date=$request->attendecnedate;
        $attendence->status_attendence=$request->atten;
        $attendence->save();
     }


}
```

Comment: You should name them differently as you have named all the students s_id and s_name you are only getting the final values. I suggest you try using s_id1, s_id2, s_id3 and so on for ids and s_name1, sname2 so that you can get each data from the loop

Comment: You should name the student id names as array. `s_id[]` so in PHP code, there will be an array with all student numbers. And when it will be submitted, you should pass the array in where condition so it will give you list of all users as array. And then loop that array using `foreach` and prepare arrays with updated values for each student, and finally call the `save()` method on the model object.

Comment: whats your dd($stdcourse1) shows ?

Comment: its for count  i have 5 recorde thats why i am getting record count in variable $stdcourse1

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: Can you please give me the code for this? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
for ($i=0; $i < $stdcourse1 ; $i++) 
{ 
    $attendence = new attendence();
    $attendence->student_id=isset($request[$i]->s_id)? $request[$i]->s_id : '0';
    $attendence->student_name=isset($request[$i]->s_name) ? $request[$i]->s_name : '';
    $attendence->course_id=isset($course1[$i]) ? $course1[$i] : '';
    $attendence->teacher_id=isset($data7[$i]) ? $data7[$i] : '';
    $attendence->date=isset($request[$i]->attendecnedate) ? $request[$i]->attendecnedate : '2018-12-20 07:00:00'; **//change this static value to dynamic one**
    $attendence->status_attendence=isset($request[$i]->atten) ? $request[$i]->atten : '';
    $attendence->save();
}
```

Comment: Error:
"Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Yes because i think in every index your values don't exist. I have updated my answer. now try it please.

Comment: Yes, You are Right. I am getting null values. Here is another error message:


"SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'student_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `attendences` (`student_id`, `student_name`, `course_id`, `teacher_id`, `date`, `status_attendence`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 1, , , , 2018-12-20 07:00:29, 2018-12-20 07:00:29)) "

Comment: then set your database fields `allow null` if you are inserting null values tooo.

Comment: No, null values not allowed. I am not getting values that is why asking here.